# ASP .NET Core & EF Core Integration Tests : unexpected datetime 1-Hour shift

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, integration-testing

I'm working on an ASP .NET Core 7 WebAPI, which handles Datetimes. I use Entity Framework Core 7 and Npgsql with Postgres.
As I want to save Datetimes without timezones to the database, I use the switch on the `AppContext` to enable it, according to [Npgsql docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html).
The issue is, in my integration test, everything is fine (date in response body is correct) until the date on the created record in the database, the `Datetime` object I get is shifted to 1 hour in the futur, event though, when I check in the database with a SQL Client, the date is correct. Here is the code of my integration test :

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task CreatePoll_CreatesPollInDb()
{
    // Given
    var createPollRequest = new CreatePollRequest
        ("Test Poll", DateTime.Now.AddDays(90), new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) } );
    
    // When
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/polls", createPollRequest);
    
    // Then
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    var pollFromResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Poll>();
    pollFromResponse.Id.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    pollFromResponse.Name.Should().Be(createPollRequest.Name);
    pollFromResponse.Dates.Should().BeEquivalentTo(createPollRequest.Dates);
    pollFromResponse.ExpirationDate.Should().Be(createPollRequest.ExpirationDate);
    
    Poll pollInDb = await DbContext.Polls.FirstAsync(record => record.Id == pollFromResponse.Id);
    pollInDb.Name.Should().Be(createPollRequest.Name);
    pollInDb.ExpirationDate.Should().Be(createPollRequest.ExpirationDate);
    pollInDb.Dates.Should().BeEquivalentTo(createPollRequest.Dates);
}
```

The `DbContext` used in the test is not the one of the application, it is created specifically for the test as a separate fixture. The test runs against a real postgres database running in Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these solutions would answers your question
[(.net) Unexpected offest when call DateTime.Today.AddDays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626811/net-unexpected-offest-when-call-datetime-today-adddays)

[DateTime.Now giving incorrect time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712404/datetime-now-giving-incorrect-time)

I would like to recommend using`DateTime utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;`then change the datetime to users time. Like the 2nd link is recommending.

Ps. This problem is not new, and has been discussed many times before.
It's not a problem of EF or asp.net.core. It's a C# issue.

```
 public class Example
 {
 public static void Main()
 {
     DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
     String[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "en-GB", "fr-FR",
                            "de-DE", "ru-RU" };

     foreach (var cultureName in cultureNames) {
     var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cultureName,
                       localDate.ToString(culture));
  }
 }
```

The example displays the following output:
en-US: 6/19/2015 10:03:06 AM

en-GB: 19/06/2015 10:03:06

fr-FR: 19/06/2015 10:03:06

de-DE: 19.06.2015 10:03:06

ru-RU: 19.06.2015 10:03:06

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-7.0